# SimpleDateFormat parsing date string incorrectly

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I'm trying to parse a String into a Date and then format that Date into a different String format for outputting.

My date formatting code is as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy h:m:s a");
String formattedDocumentDate = dateFormatter.format(dateParser.parse(sysObj.getString("document_date")));
```

The result of `sysObj.getString("document_date")` is `1/31/2013 12:00:01 AM`. And when I check the value of `formattedDocumentDate` I get `01/07/2015`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How does `1/31/2013` fit a `d/M/yyyy` date format?

Comment: one word: "lenient" (or 31-7=24 ie 2 years)

Comment: Yeah, count 31 months from the beginning of 2013 and you end up in July 2015.  Should I post that as an answer?

Comment: @DavidWallace that's the answer, so you should go for it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing days `31` as months. `SimpleDateFormat` tries to give you a valid date. Therefore It adds to 1/0/2013  **31 months**. This is 2 years and 7 month. So you get your result **01/07/2015**. So `SimpleDateFormat` works correct.

One solution for you is to change your date pattern to `M/d/yyyy h:m:s a` or your input data.

To avoid these tries you have to switch off `SimpleDateFormat` lenient mode. Then you will get an exception if the format does not fit.

Comment: "the american date format" ...or: "why satellites crash"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your input format is actually months first, then days. So should be "MM/dd/yyyy".
So:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String formattedDocumentDate = dateFormatter.format(dateParser.parse(sysObj.getString("document_date")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example like this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
System.out.println("date is:"+new java.sql.Date( sdfInput.parse("20164129").getTime() ));
```

Output is: `2019-05-29`

I expect to throw parse exception  but not (41)is not a valid month value.
on the other hand if I gave `20170229`, system can recognize the February of 2017 doesn't have a lap year and return `2017-03-01` interesting.